Server on Raspberry Pi SSH setup
I've written the 22.04 Server image to an SD card, then opened the boot partition and added a file called ssh.  Booting this gives me a system with an open SSH port.  When I log in as ubuntu@ubuntu.<my-domain> the first time, it tells me I need to change the password, which I do.  When I log in each subsequent time, it says WARNING: Your password has expired. and makes me change it again.  I seem to be stuck in a loop with this.
Is there an easy way to fix this without being able to log in to the host?  I can pop the SD card, but everything google suggests about changing password expiry implies being able to run chage on the host, which I can't.  I guess I could probably chroot into the image with QEMU but is there an easier way to fix this?

I mean, a chroot + QEMU to change the password and edit /etc/shadow to remove the "last changed" field did the job.  There's got to be a better way, though.
